# puppet set variable in nodejs module

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to install newest version of nodejs on Ubuntu by Puppet.

In my Puppet defualt.pp I include nodejs module from [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/nodejs).
I need to change variable $manage_repo in nodejs module to true (it manages to download last version of nodejs package from [Chris Lea's repo](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os)). But `$nodejs::manage_repo = true` fails with error "*Cannot assign to variables in other namespaces*" (yes I understand this).

Can you help me, how to set this variable of module from my default.pp?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I found solution few minutes after sending this question .. as always:)

If you want to set variables in module you can't include module class by `include module`, but include module like this:

```
class {'module': variable => 'value', }
```

Carefully read doc here: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/modules2.html (i was blind previous, or what?..)

Comment: You can use "include nodejs" if you put the parameter in hiera.  Puppet looks in hiera for all unspecified class parameters when compiling them (puppet > 3.0).